# Scala elegant list comprehension as in F#

Tags: scala, jdbc, list-comprehension

Just using the basic JDBC interface to read some data using Scala.
In F# (using System.Data.SqlClient namespace) we could do something like this to return an immutable list from the database.

```
    let rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    [while rs.Read() do yield rs.GetInt32(1)]
```

In Scala this proves more difficult, as far as I know there is no "while" comprehension like F#. Effectively I'd like to do something close to F# in Scala without having to use mutable vars - if only because they look ugly and add to Lines of Code.

Something like this seems to be commonplace in my Scala code right now:

```
 var result = Seq.empty[Int]
 val rs = stmt.executeQuery()
 while (rs.next()) {
     result = result :+ rs.getInt(1) }
```

Comment: Actually in idiomatic scala it would look like `val rs = stmt.executeQuery(); val result = for(r <- rs) yield r.getInt(1)` (just a pseudocode, if you will)

Comment: You may want to take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102662/scala-exposing-a-jdbc-resultset-through-a-generator-iterable/15950556#15950556

Comment: if you're looking for LINQ-like queries in scala, take a look at [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/)

Comment: om-nom-nom: actually you cant do that since rs is a recordset and can't be iterated like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would create a custom subclass of `Iterator` that wraps a query result.  It's really easy; senia showed how.

But you could also

```
val rs = stmt.executeQuery
val it = Iterator.continually(if (rs.next()) Some(rs.getInt(1)) else None)
val result = it.takeWhile(_.isDefined).toList.flatten
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use same way in scala, but I think it's ugly:

```
class Reader(var i: Int){
  def read = { i-=1; i > 0 }
  def getInt32 = i
}

val r = new Reader(10)
Stream.from(0).takeWhile{ _ => r.read}.map{ _ => r.getInt32}.toList
// List(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Idiomatic scala way is to convert your `Reader` to an `Iterator`:

```
implicit class ReaderIterator(r: Reader) extends Iterator[Int] {
  def hasNext = r.read
  def next = r.getInt32
}

scala> new Reader(10).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

But if you are really missing this syntax you could add it:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder
class FWhile(c: => Boolean){
  def apply[T](e: => T): Seq[T] = {
    val b = new VectorBuilder[T]
    while (c) b += e
    b.result
  }
}
object FWhile{
  def apply(c: => Boolean) = new FWhile(c)
}

scala> FWhile(r.read){r.getInt32}
res0: Seq[Int] = Vector(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Great answer. Upvoted all the other answers here too which are excellent.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an implicit class together with an implicit `CanBuildFrom`. This does use a mutable builder, but not at the caller's side:

```
object MyResultSetContainer {
  implicit class MyResultSet(rs: ResultSet) {
    def map[T, C <: Iterable[T]](f: (ResultSet) => T)
                               (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, C]): C = {
      val builder = cbf()
      while (rs.next()) {
        builder += f(rs)
      }
      builder.result()
    }
  }
}
```

to be used like this:

```
import MyResultSetContainer._
val rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from pg_user")

val names = for (row <- rs) yield (row.getString(1))

println(names)
rs.close()
```

The for comprehension uses `map` under the hood, so if you prefer `map` directly:

```
val names = rs.map(row => row.getString(1))
```

which produces a sequence. Thanks to `CanBuildFrom` you can produce other collections as well by providing a type explicitly:

```
val names: List[String] = rs.map(row => row.getString(1))
```

How does `CanBuildFrom` work? The Scala compiler looks at the types involved in this expression: There is the resulting type, and the type returned by the function called by map. Based on this information, the Scala compiler provides a factory implicitly which can be used to create a suitable builder. So you need only one method to produce different types of collections.

If you want to return multiple values, just return a tuple:

```
val columns = rs.map(row => (row.getInt(2), row.getString(1)))
```

and the tuple can be used to create a `Map` directly:

```
val keyNamesMap: Map[Int, String] = 
  rs.map(row => (row.getInt(2), row.getString(1)))
```

This is based on the idea that a result set is a list of rows, and so the `map` function should be available on top of it. The implicit class is used to add the `map` method to the underlying result set implicitly.

Comment: @om-nom-nom But this would destroy the magic :-) I have added an explanation.